# How to open a file with JSR 211 CHAPI (Content Handler API)

Tags: java-me, midlet

Please note that this is a question about MIDlets, i.e. Java ME (not "ordinary" Java SE).

I'm looking for the correct way to invoke content on a mobile phone using JSR 211, i.e. CHAPI - Content Handler API. I always get to the IOException in the code below. The mobile phone I'm running on supports JSR 211 (it's a Sony Ericsson C902).

```
doInvoke("file:///e:/jpgimage.jpg"); //earlier in the code

void doInvoke(final String url) {
    (new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Registry registry = Registry.getRegistry(this.getClass().getName());
                Invocation invoc = new Invocation(url);
                invoc.setAction(ContentHandler.ACTION_OPEN);
                boolean mustExit = registry.invoke(invoc);
                if (mustExit) {
                    notifyDestroyed();
                } else {
                    // stay put
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: I am stuck with a similar problem, just a quick question. why do you want to execute the invocation within a thread. Isn't it only going to run once anyway?

Comment: It was a long time ago I asked the question so I can't say I remember my decision. I think I wanted to avoid running the invocation in the UI-thread, or at least show in my question that I'm not.

Answer (score 1):

Just because a phone supports CHAPI, it doesn't mean it can specifically handle a .jpg file accessed via a Java "file://" URL.

You should only use CHAPI when the phone manufacturer directly confirms that it supports exactly what you are trying to do.

In the case of the C902, you may be better off trying to send the .jpg url (or maybe something that looks more like "/memorycard/jpimage.jpg", i.e. not a Java URL per se) to the Content-Handler-ID of the handset media center.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. A code snippet would be very appreciated.